# What does "I really cleaned out the place" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

In the comedy [*Weird Loners*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3549436/) there is an exchange,

> You guys eat up, that's plenty.
>
> I really **cleaned out the place.**

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clean out" means to empty the contents.

> [clean out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clean+out)
>
> 2.) To empty of contents or occupants.
>
> 4.) *Slang* To deprive completely of money or material wealth: The robbery cleaned us out.

So, in this context, it means the person ate all the food, though that's likely a exaggeration. Best inference of the meaning: the person ate a *bunch* of food.